# Updating Entity in Google Datastore using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, datastore

Is it possible to do an update of Entity,
replacing only the data from the input and retaining the rest of the Entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the desired effect this way:

```
   transaction.run(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        res.end(err);
    }

    transaction.get(key, function(err, entity) {
        if (err) {
            res.end(err);
        }
        if (entity) {
            entity.ImportStatus = InputImportStatus;
        } else {
            res.end('No Entity err');
        }

        transaction.save({
            key: key,
            data: entity
        });

        transaction.commit(function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(`Updated`)
            } else { res.end(err); }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do a transaction where you read the entity, update the value, write the entity.

```
function updateEntity (updateKey, newValue) {
  const transaction = datastore.transaction();

  return transaction.run()
    .then(() => transaction.get(fromKey))
    .then((result) => {
      const entity = result[0];

      entity.myProperty = newValue;

      transaction.save(
        {
          key: updateKey,
          data: entity
        }
      );

      return transaction.commit();
    })
    .catch(() => transaction.rollback());
}
```

Comment: I am still unable to do the update, I get `
{
  "textPayload": "Promise { <pending> }",
  "insertId": "000000-f365b507-72d8-48e2-a3ce-f65052545bb6",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "******",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "UpdateImportLog"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2017-09-25T11:57:45.233Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "xci8wzhqkbqj"
  },
  "logName": "projects/crypto-analyzer-180608/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "***"
}`